# Left Join in linq with multiple columns and constant value

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I'm trying to create a left join in LINQ for two tables, but one of the tables need a constant value for the join.

The query in plain SQL is

```
select 
    cf.idCreditForm ,q3.FacturadaenSAP 
from 
    Panacredit.dbo.pet_CreditForm cf
left join 
    Panacredit.dbo.cat_customentity_crediqcr3 q3 on cf.idCreditForm = q3.IdEntityItem 
                                                 and q3.IdType = 7
where  
    cf.opStatus = 6  
    and cf.idSubStatus = 72
```

and so far my LINQ code is

```
solicitudes =
    from sol in ElContexto.pet_CreditForms
    join cq3 in ElContexto.cat_customentity_crediqcr3s
    on new { sol.idCreditForm, 7 } = new { cq3.IdEntityItem , cq3.IdType }
    into solicCq3
    where sol.approvedDate >= iniDateJul
       && sol.approvedDate <= endDateJul
       && sol.opStatus == 6
       && sol.idCompany == idcompany
       && sol.idSubStatus == subEst
       && sol.idBranch == idbranch
    from scq3 in solicCq3.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { sol.idCreditForm , cq3.FacturadaenSAP };
```

Please help me

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but you need to actually ask a question. What's the issue with your current code? Please be as specific and detailed as possible.

Comment: Why would you join on a constant value rather than filtering it with a `where` clause/call first?

Answer (score 0):

The `q3.IdType = 7` part has no bearing on the join.  Move it to the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line itself.

```
join cq3 in ElContexto.cat_customentity_crediqcr3s
```

to

```
join cq3 in ElContexto.cat_customentity_crediqcr3s.Where(r => r.IdType == 7)
```

and continue join using the column idCreditForm.

Comment: This code is incomplete. It doesn't show the join clause.